# Cosmos DB : Find the index of an item in an array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to find the index number of all items in a nested array in Cosmos DB :

Data :

```
{
"id":"MyId",
"items" : [
{"id": "Item1"},
{"id" : "Item2"}
]
}
```

Query :

```
SELECT f.id, index : ** How to get the index of items ? ** 

FROM root JOIN f IN root["items"] 

WHERE (IS_DEFINED(root["items"]) AND (root["id"] = "MyId"))
```

I would like a result like this  :

```
[

{"id": "item1", "index": 0},

{"id": "item2", "index" : 1}

]
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in support on Cosmos SQL API to achieve the above result. But you can implement the following suggestions

1. You could either write your own logic in [User Defined Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-udfs) or
   retrieve the data and format it in the way you need on the Client
   Side
2. Other way is to just include the index in the data model itself